# access an element inside another element serie and index

Tags: python, pandas

i have  an issue, i have a serie (pandas.core.series.Series) and inside that serie i have an index(?¡) (pandas.core.indexes.base.Index), how do i access the element in the index part?

```
IPSA_COL[10]
```

Index(['Date', 'Open CHILE', 'High CHILE', 'Low CHILE', 'Adj Close CHILE',
'Volume CHILE', 'dif_h_o1 CHILE', 'dif_h_o2 CHILE', 'dif_h_o3 CHILE',
'dif_h_o4 CHILE', 'dif_h_o5 CHILE', 'vol_sales CHILE', 'YEAR',
'deltap1 CHILE', 'deltap2 CHILE', 'deltap3 CHILE', 'deltap4 CHILE',
'deltap5 CHILE', 'delta_vol1 CHILE', 'delta_vol2 CHILE',
'delta_vol3 CHILE', 'delta_vol4 CHILE', 'delta_vol5 CHILE'],
dtype='object')

Ho do i access the element in IPSA_COL[10]? if i need the third o last element or do i call them?

Answer (score 0):

I believe pandas indexes are subscriptable, just like regular python lists. So if you wanted the third element in the list you have above, try:

`IPSA_COL[10][2]`

Comment: Rashid Mohammed you are right i feel so dumb, have a nice day